# How to write the division values of $\operatorname{sn}(u;k)$ as rational functions of theta functions with zero argument?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, theta-functions, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

Define the "thetanulls" (theta functions (https://dlmf.nist.gov/20) with one argument equal to zero) as follows:
$$\vartheta_{00}(w) = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-w^{2n})(1+w^{2n-1})^2,$$
$$\vartheta_{01}(w) = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-w^{2n})(1-w^{2n-1})^2.$$

Then the *division values* of Jacobian elliptic functions (https://dlmf.nist.gov/22) can be written as rational functions of thetanulls:
$$\operatorname{sn}[\tfrac{1}{3}K(k);k] = \frac{2\,\vartheta _{00}[q(k)]^2}{3\,\vartheta _{00 }[q(k)^3]^2 + \vartheta_{00}[q(k)]^2} = \frac{3\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k)^3]^2 - \vartheta_{ 01}[q(k)]^2}{3\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k)^3]^2 + \vartheta_{01}[q(k)]^2},$$
$$\operatorname{cn}[\tfrac{2}{3}K(k);k] = \frac{3\,\vartheta _{00}[q(k)^3]^2 - \vartheta _{00 }[q(k)]^2}{3\,\vartheta _{00}[q(k)^3]^2 + \vartheta _{00}[q(k)]^2} = \frac{2\,\vartheta _{ 01}[q(k)]^2}{3\,\vartheta _{01}[q(k)^3]^2 + \vartheta _{01}[q(k)]^2},$$
$$\operatorname{sn}[\tfrac{1}{5}K(k);k] = \biggl\{\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k) ^5]}{\vartheta_{01}[q(k)]} - 1\biggr\}\biggl\{\frac{5\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k)^{10}]^2}{ \vartheta_{01}[q(k)^2]^2} - 1\biggr\}^{-1},$$
$$\operatorname{sn}[\tfrac{3}{5}K(k);k] = \biggl\{\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k) ^5]}{\vartheta_{01}[q(k)]} + 1\biggr\}\biggl\{\frac{5\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k)^{10}]^2}{ \vartheta_{01}[q(k)^2]^2} - 1\biggr\}^{-1},$$
$$\operatorname{cn}[\tfrac{2}{5}K(k);k] = \biggl\{\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\vartheta_{00}[q(k) ^5]}{\vartheta_{00}[q(k)]} + 1\biggr\}\biggl\{\frac{5\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k)^{10}]^2}{ \vartheta_{01}[q(k)^2]^2} - 1\biggr\}^{-1},$$
$$\operatorname{cn}[\tfrac{4}{5}K(k);k] = \biggl\{\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\vartheta_{00}[q(k) ^5]}{\vartheta_{00}[q(k)]} - 1\biggr\}\biggl\{\frac{5\,\vartheta_{01}[q(k)^{10}]^2}{ \vartheta_{01}[q(k)^2]^2} - 1\biggr\}^{-1}$$
where
$$K(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 x}}$$
and
$$q(k)=e^{-\pi\frac{K(\sqrt{1-k^2})}{K(k)}}.$$

How is this possible? It is well-known that the Jacobian functions themselves can be written as ratios of theta functions (**not** thetanulls), but theta functions with zero argument (thetanulls) apparently suffice to describe their *division values*. The above formulas are unsourced information from Wikipedia (hence I'm writing this question).

In other words, it appears that
$$\operatorname{sn}\left(\frac{aK(k)}{b};k\right)$$
is a rational function of thetanulls whenever $a/b\in\mathbb{Q}$ (or when the denominator of $a/b$ is an odd prime – this could have something to do with modular equations); the same should apply for other Jacobian elliptic functions – is it true? If so, how can that be done?

Comment: Do we perhaps get $\operatorname{sn}(\frac{1}{3}K)$ and $\operatorname{cn}(\frac{2}{3}K)$ but not vice versa: $\operatorname{cn}(\frac{1}{3}K)$ and $\operatorname{sn}(\frac{2}{3}K)$ ?